# Django 3.0.8 ' bootstrap' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:

Tags: python, django

I want a menu that's custom depending on which group you are a member of. I'm using Django 3.0.8. When I am trying to make my Templatetag it fails and it says:¨
TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/login/
'bootstrap' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
bootstrap_tags
cache
crispy_forms_field
crispy_forms_filters
crispy_forms_tags
crispy_forms_utils
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz

Error during template rendering
In template /home/saurabh/Documents/python projects/django-job-portal-master/job_portal/templates/accounts/login.html, error at line 3

'bootstrap' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of: admin_list admin_modify admin_urls bootstrap_tags cache crispy_forms_field crispy_forms_filters crispy_forms_tags crispy_forms_utils i18n l10n log static tz

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap %}

{% block content %}
<section class="home-section section-hero inner-page overlay bg-image" style="background-image: url('images/hero_1.jpg');" id="home-section">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                 <div class="mb-5 text-center">
                 and the error comes in login.html file which says,
{% load bootstrap %}
```

Comment: I don't see you using any bootstrap functionality in your template. However, it seems to me from the error message that changing `{% load bootstrap %}` to `{% load bootstrap_tags %}` should at least solve the error you're getting.

Comment: You could link the bootstrap CDN in the base.html. Because your are linking the base.html in your current file, so if you link bootstrap in base.html, then you won't need to do `{% load bootstrap %}` in your current file.

Comment: Are you trying to use the `django-bootstrap4` package?

Comment: did you add 'bootstrap' in your installed app?

Answer (score 1):

you should install:

```
pip install django-bootstrap4
```

and run it again to show the result. I hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Add bootstrap to your list of `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
     #....other apps

    'bootstrap3',

]
```